# How to make Excel formula work in all regions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to make a workbook operate in several regions that is heavy on Excel formulae.

I use the UK regional settings so the following Excel formula works fine using comma delimiter is normal for me.

```
=IF(A1=A1,"This Works","")
```

As an example, an Italian Windows/Excel version uses a semicolon delimiter eg

```
=IF(A1=A1;"This Works";"")
```

Is there an Excel ONLY setting that will allow all formula to work in any region? I thought there was one but cannot find it in Excel 2010+

**Note:** I know the regional settings can be changed in control panel eg see this [link](http://akbaraji.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/the-comma-and-semicolon-issue-in-excel-due-to-regional-settings-when-open-csv-file/) but this is not a viable solution in my case as control panel is not accessible.

Comment: AFAIK, Excel stores the commands regardless of locale. You can save a file in an UK locale and open it in an Italian locale the same... The only limitation I know is that while on a locale, you have to type as the locale expects.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard That is correct. I confirmed it by [downloading an english Excel file](https://docs.google.com/viewer?docex=1&url=http://cdcontent.books24x7.com/id_16959/text%20formula%20examples.xlsx) and [opening it in a german Excel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ND0z3.png). As we see, commas are converted to semicolons and english formula names appear as their german counterparts. The same is true vice-versa

Comment: Thanks! It works here too. There must be some other reason a client is reporting errors. Maybe it has VBA that is applying formula. If you add that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores *native* formulas in the file regardless of locale. As an example, you can save a file in an English locale and open it in an Italian or German locale.

In fact and as you mentioned, the way Excel *expects* formulas to be written is *somewhat* related to the Regional Settings of the machine and of the version of Excel being used. In any given machine, you have to type formulas as the locale expects it. After saving, any version of Excel should open and "convert" the `,` to `;` and vice-versa, accordingly.

On a side note, VBA scripting should be independent of locale, unless the scripts expected some character to be present.

Comment: what about date formatting?

Comment: I can't understand why Excel would work this way, it's insane. I want to do x in Excel, but every solution I find doesn't work because my Excel expects Dutch formulas.

Comment: @s1h4d0w excel has completely failed in terms of regional settings. SUM() AVG() and all other formulas should work the exact same way everywhere in the world. How M$ managed to mess this up is simply beyond me.